# Do PHP session files normally count towards disk usage on shared hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, disk-space-utilization, shared-hosting

Do PHP session files normally count towards disk usage on shared hosting?

The title is pretty much the question.  The files are outside of my home directory, so I can't delete them.  They include some deleted backups too.  The paths to the files that are using up a third of my allotted disk space are:

```
/backup2/cpbackup/deleted/kelseyto/
/home/virtfs/linksolu/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70/
/home/virtfs/byteware/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70/
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70/
```

Comment: Did not asking to your provider ? Or check its documentation ? Without the name of the provider, we will not be able to help you...

Comment: We don't accept questions about shared web hosting here. You should contact your hosting provider for assistance with this issue.

Comment: I was asking as a general trend, not as specific to one provider.